# Simple JSON deserializaiton

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I know this is not hard, but I've been staring at the JSON.Net documentation for a half hour and don't see how it works.  I've got it setup, but my initial attempts are failing and the documenation that I have looked at so far isn't making it obvious (to me, at least) how to deserialize the array form response.data and then get at the individual fields of each record.

Also, I don't need to use JSON.Net - it just seemed like a good choice.  Any solution will do just fine.

```
{
    "request":{
        "Format":"json",
        "Target":"Affiliate",
        "Method":"findAll",
        "Service":"HasOffers",
        "Version":"2",
        "NetworkId":"directagents",
        "NetworkToken":"......"
    },
    "response":{
        "status":1,
        "data":{
            "2056":{
                "Affiliate":{
                    "id":"2056",
                    "company":
                    "123 Greetings 123 Greetings (CD186)",
                    "address1":"1 Change Address",
                    "address2":"",
                    "city":"City",
                    "region":"NY",
                    "country":"US",
                    "other":null,
                    "zipcode":"11111",
                    "phone":"-",
                    "fax":null,
                    "website":null,
                    "signup_ip":null,
                    "date_added":"2012-02-24 18:00:24",
                    "modified":-62169966000,
                    "ref_id":"CD186",
                    "status":"pending",
                    "wants_alerts":"1",
                    "account_manager_id":"20",
                    "payment_method":"check",
                    "payment_terms":"net 30",
                    "w9_filed":"0",
                    "referral_id":null,
                    "affiliate_tier_id":null,
                    "fraud_activity_score":null,
                    "fraud_activity_alert_threshold":null,
                    "fraud_activity_block_threshold":null,
                    "fraud_profile_alert_threshold":null,
                    "fraud_profile_block_threshold":null,
                    "scrub_offer_pixels":null,
                    "shared":"0"
                    }
                },
            "1606":{
                                   .......this is enough to see how its structured....
```

Comment: What are you deserializing as?  Can you post the classes?

Comment: That might be my problem, i don't have any classes.  I have a JSON string from an HTTP API.

Comment: i tried to find a utility that generates classes from example json, but no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could model that “array” as `Dictionary<int, AffiliateHolder>`. The classes for that JSON could look like this:

```
class Top
{
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

class Request
{
    public string Format { get;set; }
    // etc.
}

class Response
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, AffiliateHolder> Data { get; set; }
}

class AffiliateHolder
{
    public Affiliate Affiliate { get; set; }
}

class Affiliate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // etc.
}

var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Top>(myJSONString);
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest, easiest way is to use Json.NET and LINQ to Json.  Given your example above, the following code:

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
foreach (var item in parsedJson["response"]["data"])
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

would write out the following to the console:

```
"2056": {
  "Affiliate": {
    "id": "2056",
    "company": "123 Greetings 123 Greetings (CD186)",
    "address1": "1 Change Address",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "City",
    "region": "NY",
    "country": "US",
    "other": null,
    "zipcode": "11111",
    "phone": "-",
    "fax": null,
    "website": null,
    "signup_ip": null,
    "date_added": "2012-02-24 18:00:24",
    "modified": -62169966000,
    "ref_id": "CD186",
    "status": "pending",
    "wants_alerts": "1",
    "account_manager_id": "20",
    "payment_method": "check",
    "payment_terms": "net 30",
    "w9_filed": "0",
    "referral_id": null,
    "affiliate_tier_id": null,
    "fraud_activity_score": null,
    "fraud_activity_alert_threshold": null,
    "fraud_activity_block_threshold": null,
    "fraud_profile_alert_threshold": null,
    "fraud_profile_block_threshold": null,
    "scrub_offer_pixels": null,
    "shared": "0"
  }
}
```

It is not necessary to create concrete classes for explicit deserialization.  Obviously that is a perfectly valid approach, however, if that's your style preference.

See http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/LINQtoJSON.html for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try creating a simple example, not a huge json like that one.
Take a look at http://servicestack.net/ it is an alternative to Json.NET, it is faster and the learning curve is small. You can find a lot of examples on the website.

Comment: So how would you deserialize that array at `response.data`?

Answer (score -1):

Is this in javascript? You should be able to just do this:

```
JSON.parse(response.data)
```

Comment: my target language is actually C#, and the code example is a string that is obtained from an HTTP GET...